# is there a limit for running multiple 32 bit JVMs?

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory, 32-bit

I am working on a remote server with 64G of ram, I am using a platform which is using 32bit JVM and what I have to do is to create multiple JVMs (around 500). what happens is that after creating 190 or so I get the OOM error from java which says unable to create new native thread. Each JVM occupies around 20M of RAM so 20*190 is around 4G.
So is there any limit on the memory used by all the JVMs together? BTW my process limit in Linux is around 10000 and the limit in /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max is 65000, and also I don't get this lack of resources with other processes. Another point, changing the heap size doesn't help either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to heap size. It is related to the number of threads you are able to create.

When you run a JVM, you have a lot of threads that are created (and active). I can count at least 25 of them. For instance, there are threads for Timer tasks, compiler threads, Finalizer threads and of course GC threads.

Apart from SerialGC, every garbage collector creates a number of thread proportional to the number of cores you have, so it can have a huge impact on the number of threads per JVM.

Some things to do :

- Increase your process limit
- Set a maximum number of threads (`-XX:ConcGCThreads=N`, `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=N`)
- Do some thread dumps to check the number of threads in a JVM and deduce the right number for your platform

More JVM options : http://jvm-options.tech.xebia.fr/

Hope that helps !